# JavaScript PostgreSQL - cannot insert more than 2 chars in INSERT

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql, psql

I have a problem. I cannot send a query(just example):

```
INSERT INTO base1(id, f1) VALUES(1, 'abc');
```

An error from console:

> Error: pq: value too long for type character(1)

For another example, I can do this:

```
INSERT INTO base1(id, f1) VALUES(1, 'ab');
```

I tried so many solutions, but without an effect. I'm a newbie so I guess there is a limit querying from the scripts? I tried to put it in the console and I can do it, just a script cannot pass :(

[Edit 1]

I forgot about a script from creating a table:

```
CREATE TABLE base1 
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    f1 TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

[Edit 2]

Source table and code:

```
 CREATE TABLE ip_logs
 (
      ip_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
      nickname TEXT, 
      ip_adress TEXT
 );

 INSERT INTO ip_logs (ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) 
 VALUES (20, 'test', 'test')
```

DESCRIPTION table:

[image: 1]

Comment: Yes, it seems to be easy. But if u can see, the structure of table have not a maximum length(TEXT type is unlimitted).

Comment: strings should be in single quotes not double quote , double quote is used for object names. so I'm not sure why you are not getting error message related to that . replace double quotes with single quotes and try agian

Comment: It was just an example, the source is: "INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) VALUES (20, 'test', 'test')", but help for this information.

Comment: Run `DESCRIBE base1;` and show us the result

Comment: [Looks, like](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8f976/1) double quote issue in deed (as @eshirvana noted). Double quoted `"abc"` is understood as a column name.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov its changed, just my bad with writting an example.

Comment: @HTMHell Look at picture in main thread.

Comment: @Zarezerwowany wrong table? your picture shows scheme of `ip_logs` table and your question is about `base1`

Comment: What does this have to do with Javascript? And it's very unclear with the edits what your question is. Post the **actual** table and **actual** query you have questions about, without mixing and matching and switching. Javascript is a lot more forgiving (for instance about the difference between ' and ") than postgres.

Comment: I use javascript to do this querry and I think its blame of javascript. I dont know why, I can do all the querries local on my own server.

Comment: @Zarezerwowany you don't have any JS code posted, so how are we supposed to help you with it?

Comment: if datatype is already 'text' you shouldn't be getting this error, either you are referring to the different table than the one you are inserting to

Comment: @eshirvana i checked it by deleting the table and trying to do the same -> I got an error about missing table.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error would occur if the text column was declared as `character(1)`:

```
create table base1 (
    id int primary key,
    f1 character(1) not null
);
insert into base1 (id, f1) values (1, 'abc');
-- ERROR:  value too long for type character(1)
```

`character(1)` allows just one character. You would need to change the datatype or length to something that better suits your need:

```
alter table base1 alter column f1 type text;
insert into base1 (id, f1) values (1, 'abc');
-- 1 rows affected
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=240d03c6b9445baf55206842a7989860)**

Comment: Look at the main thread. I added my constructor of table. I have a TEXT type already. I will try to change TEXT to TEXT but I think its not it cuz I can do this command on the server but not in the script.

Comment: Sounds like you are connecting to 2 separate databases. To check run "Select current_database();"  from both psql  connection and via your Java Script.